# density function of $-Y$

Tags: probability

I'm reading the proof of the difference of density functions $Z=X-Y$:$f_Z(z)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f_X(x)f_{-Y}(z-x)dx$

Then I came into 
$$f_{-Y}(z-x)=f_{Y}(x-z)$$

Can smb explain why this is true?

Answer (score 1):

In general if $f$ serves as density of random variable $Y$ then the function prescribed by $y\mapsto f(-y)$ serves as density of random variable $-Y$.

This because: $$\{-Y\in B\}=\{Y\in -B\}$$ where $-B:=\{-x\mid x\in B\}$ so that: $$P(-Y\in B)=P(Y\in-B)=\int\mathbf1_{-B}(y)f(y)dy=\int\mathbf1_{B}(-y)f(y)dy=\int\mathbf 1_B(z)f(-z)dz$$

The last equality is attained by substituting $z=-y$.

Answer (score 0):

Call $W = -Y$, then you have

$$
\require{cancel}
f_W(w) = f_Y(y)\cancelto{1}{\left|\frac{{\rm d}y}{{\rm d}w} \right| }
$$

So you have

$$
f_{-Y}(y) = f_Y(-y)
$$